# Ionic 5: change Knob size when pressed

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I would like to know is there a way to change the knob-size of an "ion-range" while pressed. I've been looking at the documentation, but no info appears to be in the "ion-range" section. I would like to edit this info on SCSS:

Normal Behavior

[image: Normal Behavior]

Pressed behavior

[image: Pressed behavior]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find how to these things is usually to inspect the code (for example using Chrome DevTools) and see if Ionic adds a class to the `ion-range` when pressing it.

In this case, that's exactly what happens. When pressing the `ion-range` Ionic adds the `range-pressed` class so you can use that class to update the size of the knob like this:

```
ion-range {
  &.range-pressed {
    --knob-size: 44px; // Use any size you want here!
  }
}
```

Please take a look at **[this Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66374872?file=src/app/pages/home/home.page.scss)**:

[image: Demo project]